# Yii : form values retention for CHtml::checkBoxList on form validaton

Tags: validation, yii

I am using CHtml::checkBoxList for my form.  For some reason I cannot use CHtml:activeCheckBoxList or CActiveForm::checkBoxList. Everything works fine only problem is that I loose checkbox values on form validation error.  What could be the easiest way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a form, you probably want to use [CActiveForm's checkboxlist](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#checkBoxList-detail), which is a form-specific wrapper of CHtml::activeCheckBoxList) instead. Something like

```
echo $form->checkBoxList(
                $model, 
                'condiments', 
                array(
                    'ketchup'=>'Ketchup', 
                    'mustard'=>'Mustard',
                    'relish'=>'Relish',
                    'onions'=>'Onions'
                    )
                );
```

should give you a persistent check box list of hot dog condiments, for example.

Comment: Sorry, when you wrote "For some reason I cannot use CHtml:activeCheckBoxList" I assumed you meant you couldn't get it to work but couldn't figure out why, and so I was trying to encourage you to give it another shot. Is there a specific reason you can't use activeCheckBoxList?